# Search data from data.json file with keyword

Tags: html, json

I want to make a mini dictionary with JSON file. I did my code by watching tutorial from Youtube. It's work in that video with that codes but it's not working in my pc. What's wrong with my code? Please guide me.

Here is my **data.json**

```
[
  {
     "id":"1",
     "scientific":"Orchidaceae",
     "varnicular":"Thit Khwa",
     "family":"red",
     "order":"red",
     "kingdom":"red",
     "english":"Orchid"
  },
  {  
     "id":"2",
     "scientific":"test",
     "varnicular":"test",
     "family":"test",
     "order":"test",
     "kingdom":"test",
     "english":"test"
  },
  {
     "id":"3",
     "scientific":"test2",
     "varnicular":"test2",
     "family":"test2",
     "order":"test2",
     "kingdom":"test2",
     "english":"test2"
  },
  {  
     "id":"4",
     "scientific":"test3",
     "varnicular":"test3",
     "family":"test3",
     "order":"test3",
     "kingdom":"test3",
     "english":"test3"
  },
  {  
     "id":"5",
     "scientific":"test4",
     "varnicular":"test4",
     "family":"test4",
     "order":"test4",
     "kingdom":"test4",
     "english":"test4"
  },
  {  
     "id":"6",
     "scientific":"test5",
     "varnicular":"test5",
     "family":"test5",
     "order":"test5",
     "kingdom":"test5",
     "english":"test5"
  },
  {  
     "id":"7",
     "scientific":"test6",
     "varnicular":"test6",
     "family":"test6",
     "order":"test6",
     "kingdom":"test6",
     "english":"test6"
  }
]
```

Here is my **index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
<p><br/><br/></p>
<div class="container">
    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search" /><br/>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Scientific Name</th>
                <th>English Name</th>
                <th>Varnicular Name</th>
                <th>Family</th>
                <th>Order</th>
                <th>Kingdom</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  s('#search').keydown(function(){
    s.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
      var search = s('#search').val();
      var regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
      var output;
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
        if((val.scientific.search(regex)) != -1 || (val.english.search(regex)) != -1 || (val.varnicular.search(regex)) != -1){
          output += "<tr>";
          output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.id+"</td>";
          output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.scientific+"</td>";
          output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.english+"</td>";
          output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.varnicular+"</td>";
          output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.family+"</td>";
          output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.order+"</td>";
          output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.kingdom+"</td>";
          output += "</tr>";
        }
      });
      $('tbody').html(output);
    });
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for waste your time guys. I found my error. I was coded wrong with ***s*** instead of ***$***

I changed my code here

```
$('#search').keydown(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
      var search = $('#search').val();
      var regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
      var output;
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all "c(" to "$(" in your code.

Edit:
and "c." to "$." too